# How to document Flutter widgets and screens classes in my app?

Tags: flutter, dart, documentation, flutter-widget

I don't know what is the common way and best practices used in documenting UI widgets and components in a Flutter app, I could find a good resource on how to document dart code in general [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation)
And how you can describe a function behavior or a model attribute.
But what is the best way to add comments for UI Classes, Screens, Refactored Widgets, etc..
so that it can be helpful and describes the widget or the screen contents?

Answer (score 2):

The whole flutter project is open source. You could always check how the flutter team documents its widgets.

For example, here is the source of the `Container` widget:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart

Personally, I would only document widgets which I publish as part of a library. But tastes are different :D

Comment: Yes I share your opinion but I was thinking to make life easier for those who will work after me, I don't know what is the best practices to leave the code in a good state for future developers, I don't know if widget documentation can help them and how to do it efficiently :D